# What does ISAC stand for?

Tags: the-division

When completing missions and encounters in the game you are often given directions by 'ISAC'. The voice sounds like it's a computer, so my assumption is that ISAC is actually an acronym.

So what does ISAC stand for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ISAC stands for "Intelligent System Analytic Computer". It is confirmed at the beginning of the game, as you can see in this [playthrough video](https://youtu.be/CJMuw2A9Qds?t=5m8s) at 5 minutes and 8 seconds.

It is also confirmed by the [tvtropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/VideoGame/TheDivision) site :

> ISAC, the personal assistant AI used by Agents to give them updates and alerts stands for "Intelligent System Analytic Computer".

The [Famitsu](http://www.famitsu.com/matome/division/glossary.html)'s glossary page for The Division also confirm it from what we can read from it :

> ■ISAC
>   “Intelligent System Analytic Computer”の略称。膨大な情報を一元管理して伝達し、現場のエージェントをつねにサポートしてくれる。

Comment: I remember that ISAC tells you what the acronym stands for when it introduces itself, if anybody wants to try to confirm it.

Comment: I started a new game yesterday, and I can confirm that ISAC introduces itself as "Intelligent System Analytic Computer" in-game.

Comment: I was looking for a playthrough video where he was saying that. Thanks for the confirm !